# What happens if a Drobo experiences a power failure during a rebuild?

Tags: raid, power, ups, drobo, redundancy

I recently purchased a Drobo and I was wondering, what happens to the Drobo if it's in the middle of a rebuild and there's a power failure? I know that the Drobo cannot protect against a disk failure when it's rebuilding the array, but I haven't been able to find any information on what would happen if a power failure occurs during a rebuild.

Comment: If you just purchased it, test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.datarobotics.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/195

> All Drobo storage devices have  internal batteries which protect critical information during an unexpected power loss.

One would assume drobo engineers also protect data when performing a rebuild.

you can make a post on the Drobo forums

http://www.drobospace.com/forums/